# Are multiple articles needed in genitive list?

Tags: article, genitive, list

If the English sentence were

> It was a time of happiness, peace and joy.

would the German be the following?

> Es war eine Zeit des Glücks, des Friedens und der Freude

That seems clumsy to me, but I also don't think a construction like

> eine Zeit des Glücks, Friedens und (der?) Freude

is permissible.

Comment: Welcome to German SE and thanks for this good question!

Comment: You used the *Oxford Comma* in German, and omitted it in English. Strange.

Comment: I corrected a minor spelling mistake and a wrong comma. In German, there is no comma in a list before the "und": `des Glücks, des Friedens [kein Komma] und der Freude`. See: "Das Komma bei Reihungen (Aufzählungen)" https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma

Comment: @Janka - I did not know that such thing exists :)  - well, I'm only basic english speaker ;-) my quick source: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/

Comment: To clarify: in German, using that comma before *und* in a list is a punctuation error. A comma before *und* indicates a new main clause, not the end of a list of items.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can omit repeated articles in genitive.

> Wir gedenken der Verwundeten, Gefallenen und Vermissten des Krieges
>
> Es war eine Zeit des Glücks, Friedens und fröhlichen Zusammenseins

The genitive is, while still present, one of the rarer cases in German.

So, while you *can* omit repeated articles in lists, you might want to refrain from doing so to clearly mark the genitive. Note I changed your example - mixed articles (omitted/present) in lists in genitive sound, while grammatically entirely correct, a bit awkward to a native speaker. So I would rather use your example as

> Es war eine Zeit des Glücks, des Friedens und der Freude

instead of

> Es war eine Zeit des Glücks, Friedens und der Freude

But that detail is more a matter of style than of grammar.

Comment: I guess you wanted to note "if you omit articles they should be omitted after the first article for the entire list"? Because that is what I read from your examples. (and I could not find a different example atm)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm Yep - you simply avoid repetition, but the first one must be present

Comment: (k, I meant it as hint for you with the small Zaunspfahl to integrate it in your answer, would be only difference so far that's why I didn't want to create a separate one)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm I think the first sentence of my answer covers that point. "Yes, you can omit **repeated** articles in genitive"

Comment: You can opt to avoid the article and the genitive in various ways. e.g. "Eine Zeit voll Glück und Frieden". "Im Gedenken an Verletzte, Gefallene, und Vermisste des Krieges". What a luck that the verb "vermissen" commands a different case, so confusion is unlikely with "Wir gedachten den verwundeten Gefallenen, und vermissten den Krieg". You might not be so lucky with other verb/adjective/etc pairs.

Comment: @vectory I'm not so sure that the question was *how to avoid* saying something, but rather how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to tofro's [answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50444/36160) I only want to point out/ stress some hints from the comments:

*If* you want to omit repeated articles than you often (not always*) need the first and (always) omit the rest.

You just have to be aware which nouns are part of your list to have omitted articles.

In comparison the two examples:

`Wir gedenken der Verwundeten, der Gefallenen und der Vermissten des Krieges.`=>

> Wir gedenken der Verwundeten, Gefallenen und Vermissten des Krieges.

`Es war eine Zeit des Glücks, des Friedens und des fröhlichen Zusammenseins.`=>

> Es war eine Zeit des Glücks, Friedens und fröhlichen Zusammenseins.

As you might see: `des Krieges`is in genitive but not part of the list.

*As [vectory](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/35977/vectory) points out, you can even have sentence constructions to omit all articles:

> Eine Zeit voll Glück und Frieden. Im Gedenken an Verletzte, Gefallene und Vermisste des Krieges.

**When to omit and when not?** 
In my opinion it depends on overall context. With the articles I can stress more the nouns, without it is more a "long concatenated list".

That is why I would prefer `an die Verletzten, ...` because it is feels like a reverent moment speaking about it. In other cases they make the sentence longer and I guess in speaking I would more likely omit them while in writing put the articles there. <sub>Or maybe just thinking about the sentence let me put them in and not long thinking omits them. Good question.</sub>